# Rails SystemStackError (stack level too deep) in actionpack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, controller, actionpack

today I got to an error with my Ruby on Rails API and I can't figure out what the problem is. Whenever I try to create a new Character in my Controller I always get an SystemStackError and I have no Idea why. I will post the relevant Files below.

characters_controller.rb

```
module Api
module V1
    class CharactersController < ApplicationController
        def index
            @chars = Character.all
            respond_to do |format|
                format.json { render :json => @chars }
            end
        end
        def create
            @newchar = Character.new

            lastmod = params[:lastModified]
            charname = params[:name]
            realm = params[:realm]
            battlegroup = params[:battlegroup]
            charclass = params[:class]
            race = params[:race]
            gender = params[:gender]
            level = params[:level]
            achievement_points = params[:achievementPoints]
            thumbnailurl = params[:thumbnailurl]
            itemlvltotal = params[:itemleveltotal]
            itemlvlequipped = params[:itemlevelequipped]
            userid = params[:userid]

            @newchar.lastModified = lastmod
            @newchar.name = charname
            @newchar.realm = realm
            @newchar.battlegroup = battlegroup
            @newchar.class = charclass
            @newchar.race = race
            @newchar.gender = gender
            @newchar.level = level
            @newchar.achievementPoints = achievement_points
            @newchar.thumbnailurl = thumbnailurl
            @newchar.itemleveltotal = itemlvltotal
            @newchar.itemlevelequipped = itemlvlequipped
            @newchar.userid = userid

            if @newchar.save!
                render json: {status: 'success', code: 0, message: 'Character has been saved'}
            else
                render json: {status: 'error', code: 1, message: 'Failed to save character'}
            end
        end
        def update 
        end
        def mychars
            @chars = Character.where(userid: params[:userid])
            render json: {characters: @chars}
        end
    end
end
end
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 namespace :api, :defaults => {:format => :json} do
namespace :v1 do

    resources :users do
    collection do
      post 'register'
      post 'login'
      get 'make_moderator'
    end
  end

  resources :raids do
    collection do
      post 'create'
      get 'details'
      post 'sign_up'
      post 'sign_off'
      post 'signedup'
    end
  end

  resources :characters do
    collection do
      get 'mychars'
      post 'create'
      post 'update'
    end
  end

  end
 end
end
```

character.rb (my model)

```
class Character < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
end
```

The error (stacktrace) I get is:

```
Started POST "/api/v1/characters/create" for 82.112.107.65 at 2015-01-07 17:30:10 +0100
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM     "schema_migrations"
Processing by Api::V1::CharactersController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"lastModified"=>"1194551616", "name"=>"Mortan", "realm"=>"Kargath",     "battlegroup"=>"Reckoning / Abrechnung", "class"=>"5", "race"=>"4", "gender"=>"0", "level"=>"72", "achievementPoints"=>"7245", "thumbnailurl"=>"http://eu.battle.net/static-render/eu/kargath/240/386800-avatar.jpg", "itemleveltotal"=>"137", "itemlevelequipped"=>"127", "userid"=>"10"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 26ms

SystemStackError (stack level too deep):
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:79


  Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-    4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (0.9ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.8ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.8ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (29.0ms)
```

Any help is appreciated since I don't know how to handle this problem :) thanks

EDIT: Whenever I try to send the same request again I get a different error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/api/v1/characters_controller.rb:11:in `create'


  Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (1.2ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (2.2ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.8ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (28.3ms)
```

Where line 11 is:

```
@newchar = Character.new
```

Comment: Almost certainly this line, `@newchar.class = charclass`, call the attribute something else like `character_class`.

Comment: Changed it and it still appears with the same error, what I also noticed is that If I try to do the same request again the request fails with the error: NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/api/v1/characters_controller.rb:11:in `create' which is the line: @newchar = Character.new in my controller

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace please.

Comment: This is the full stack trace I got

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this problem was to rename the attribute of Character named class. This has somehow caused the error and after changing it the problem was gone. Thanks to everyone who helped me with this problem.

Comment: Can confirm, same problem, same solution.

Comment: I've been tearing my hair out due to this issue (just upgraded to Rails 4.1.2 and was convinced the upgrade was the cause).. thank you SO much for this answer!